# como puedo agregar un dato sin llamar ala funcion que trae los datos nuevamente?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguente duda tengo un formulario donde creo un producto la duda , agregar a la vista dicho producto sin llamar a la funcion getAllProducts que es la que me trae todos los demas productos.

dejo aqui mi codigo

```html
<script>

 onMount( () => {
       getAllProducts();
    })
  
  
  const createNewProduct = async (product)=> {
         if(product){
               try {
                currentProduct= await newProduct(product);
                console.log(currentProduct);
                products.push(currentProduct);
                getAllProduct();
                }catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
               }
           }
    }


</script>
```

me gustaria saber si hay una mejor manera sin que tenga que llamar a getAllProducts() dento de createNewProducts()

Comment: Imagino que la función newProduct es la que se encarga de realizar la insersión en la BD no?

Comment: si newProduct, es la que guarda el dato en la bd y getAllproducts muestra en cards de boostrap algunos detalles de estos productos , la duda es si hay alguna mejor manera de agregar el prducto sin tener que llamar por debajo a esa funcion de allProducts

Comment: Para ello deberías de guardar localmente todos los productos cuando los recuperas (en memoria lo más sencillo, según lo que necesites -persistencia, etc-), en una especie de store o almacén a nivel de cliente/front. Cuando creas uno nuevo y todo ha ido correcto (llamada HTTP, inserción BD, etc), entonces se puede considerar que ese producto puede pasar y actualizar ese store o almacén. Otra opción sería que, dado que tienes que hacer una llamada sí o sí a back para añadir un nuevo producto, que la respuesta te devuelva todos los producto, así te despreocupas de mantener esa estructura tú.

Comment: @MatiasArturoGonzálezRoa entonces es fácil. Imagino que la función newProduct devuelve algún código o estado donde dice si se inserto correctamente o no; entonces dado eso, puedes realizar el push al arreglo original con el nuevo producto basándote en si el ingreso en la BD fue correcto o no. Me explico?

Comment: ok Pablo lo pondré en practica ahora , gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Si tienes alguna duda, pregunta y te ayudo 